# Can't connect to Gitlab repositories with multiple keys

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

I have two Gitlab repositories, owned by two different users. Let's call them

- **personal**: git@gitlab.com:user1/personal.git
- **work**: git@gitlab.com:user2/work.git

I got two RSA keys: with key1 I can usually connect to personal repo; with key2 to work repo.
I have to push/pull from different workstations (Mac OS / Windows); on every machine, I can connect to the first or the second repo with no problems.

From a single Windows 10 workstation I need to connect to *both* repositories and here start the troubles.
On that workstation, I use Git Bash.

According to different guides (e.g. https://coderwall.com/p/7smjkq/multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-accounts-on-github-or-gitlab), I've setup a `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitlab-personal
        HostName gitlab.com
        User git
        LogLevel DEBUG3
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
        #IdentitiesOnly yes

Host gitlab-work
        HostName gitlab.com
        User git
        LogLevel DEBUG3
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
        #IdentitiesOnly yes
```

If I run
`ssh -Tv git@gitlab-personal`
I got:

```
...
Welcome to Gitlab, User1!
...
```

And if I run
`ssh -Tv git@gitlab-work`
I got:

```
...
Welcome to Gitlab, User2!
...
```

This makes me think that RSA keys are setup correctly (even in Putty / Pageant).

But if I try to clone the repositories, for example

```
git clone git@gitlab-personal:user1/personal.git
```

or

```
git clone git@gitlab-work:user2/work.git
```

..in both cases I got this response:

```
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to anyone who can help me.